# Using Zend Framework 1 library in Laminas API tools - auto loading vendor prefix class

Tags: php, autoload, laminas-api-tools, vendor-prefix, laminas

I am working on a Laminas API tools (version 1.4) project. There is ZF1 library which I need in my code. the structure of library is:

```
DirectoryA
          .DirectoryB
            file1.php =====> DirectoryA_DirectoryA_className
```

as shown above class names are *vendor prefix*.

when I use this class in my code the use statement is like below:

`use DirectoryA_DirectoryA_className`

but in runtime I get **Class DirectoryA_DirectoryA_className not found** error.

my autoloading config in *composer.json* file:

```
 "autoload": {
   "psr-0": {
     "DirectoryA_": "/lib/DirectoryA/DirectoryB" 
   }
 },
```

also tried "DirectoryA_": "/lib/DirectoryA" ,"DirectoryA_": "/lib"

I am new in PHP, any help would be appreciated.